# Can't open Private window in Edge Browser using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, private

I have tried below mentioned code, but its not working in my framework.
Selenium -3.141.59
Microsoft Edge- 81.0.416.72

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.setCapability("inPrivate", true); 
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Which language are you using to do the Edge Driver test?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add argument `inprivate` to make Edge Chromium open in Private mode using Selenium WebDriver.

Please refer to the following steps:

Download the language binding of Selenium 4.00-alpha05 from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

Download the matching version of Microsoft Edge Driver from [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads).

Then, using the following code (it works well in C# and Java application):

```
    EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
    edgeOptions.addArguments("-inprivate");
    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
```